# Source not found for Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I've come across some really strange behaviour in my Java code. There is a exception shown on my Eclipse log console saying `Exception:java.lang.NullPointerException` with no reference to the code where it occurred.

On debugging I found out a line where this occurred and so put it in `try-catch` hoping I catch it. However it didn't return in catch block.

The strange part being even though there's exception thrown at the line immediately after it executes and the execution continues normally.

Can some one please tell me the probable cause?
I could have attached the source code but I have checked the parameters and all seem fine.

My main reason for this post is to learn about such behavior if any of you coders ever came across.

Comment: you can also clean your project

Comment: I think your compiled code is out of sync with your source code

Comment: Where does it appear - Console or Error log?

Comment: @Nishant Console and error log shows org.eclipse.plugin ...does it imply Ecplise issue??

Comment: `Console` and `Error Log` are two different views in eclipse. If the error appears in `Console` view its most likely coming from your code. Errors appearing in the `Error Log` view are related to eclipse issues like it not being able to understand user input.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a problem with Eclipse. I have seen that behaviour before, and restarting Eclipse solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether your builder is activated and the changed source code is build automatically. Otherwise your code changes will never get it into your runtime application.

I am pretty sure, that the executed source code is different to the source code shown in your editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the exception's message but no stack trace, that is caused by code that looks like this:

```
try
    {
    // something which causes the exception
    }
catch (final Exception err)
    {
    System.out.println(err);
    }
```

The problem with this code is that it only prints the result of the exception's `.toString()` method.  For most exceptions this is just the exception class and the message.  This code omits the stack trace, thus making it much harder to debug the problem.

If the exception is to be caught, then change the code to look like this for the stack trace to be included in the output:

```
try
    {
    // something which causes the exception
    }
catch (final Exception err)
    {
    err.printStackTrace();
    }
```